# How to square a matrix-vector expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How get I from this
$\Big(bA(k_0-k_1)\Big)^2$ to this $ (k_0-k_1)^TA^Tb^TbA(k_0-k_1)
$?

Comment: Please explain what is $b, A, k_{0},\dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, $b$ is a $1\times m$ row vector and $k_0$ and $k_1$ are $n\times 1$ column vectors, then 
$$
bA(k_0-k_1)
$$
is a $1\times 1$ matrix, in other words, a number.  Since the transpose of a $1\times 1$ matrix doesn't change the matrix, 
$$
bA(k_0-k_1)=(bA(k_0-k_1))^T=(k_0-k_1)^TA^Tb^T.
$$